BuildConfig Field Unresolved in CI/CD
I'm trying to complete a pipeline on Github Actions.  For the Build and Analyze phase, which runs sonar cloud task I keep getting the same error.
2024-10-30T15:16:50.9205990Z e: file:///home/runner/work/mo-android/mo-android/app/src/main/java/menu/quor/wrappers/BuildConfigWrapper.kt:13:39 Unresolved reference: VERSION_NAME
2024-10-30T15:16:50.9209299Z e: file:///home/runner/work/mo-android/mo-android/app/src/main/java/menu/quor/wrappers/BuildConfigWrapper.kt:25:40 Unresolved reference: VERSION_CODE

For reference, here is my buildconfig wrapper:
    fun getLanguage() = Locale.getDefault().language

    fun getOperatingSystemVersion() = ""+Build.VERSION.RELEASE

    fun getAppVersion() = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME

    fun getTimeZone() = Calendar.getInstance().timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)

    fun getIsDebugBuild() = BuildConfig.DEBUG

    fun getAppID() = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

    fun getProductName() = BuildConfig.PRODUCT_NAME

    fun getBuildType() = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE

    fun getBuildNumber() = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
}

Here is my yml file for this Github Action:
#1
name: JFrog - Test

## Actions to be executed when creating PR
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  unit_tests:
    name: Run Unit Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v4.5.0
        with:
          distribution: "temurin"
          java-version: 17
          
      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Run All Module Tests
        run: ./gradlew JacocoBbsandboxDebugCodeCoverage

  build:
    name: Build and analyze
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis

      - name: Authenticate JFrog
        uses: jfrog/setup-jfrog-cli@v4.4.1
        env:
          JF_URL: ${{ secrets.J_FROG_URL }}
          JF_USER: ${{ secrets.J_FROG_USERNAME }}
          JF_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.J_FROG_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4.5.0
        with:
          distribution: "temurin"
          java-version: 17

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/actions/setup-gradle@v4

      - name: Build Sandbox
        run: ./gradlew build[required variant]

      - name: Cache SonarCloud packages
        uses: actions/cache@v4.1.2
        with:
          path: ~/.sonar/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build and Analyze
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: ./gradlew build sonarqube --info

If anyone can tell me how to over come this I would really really appreciate it
EDIT
Adding flavours from gradle.
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        val apiSaltHash: String by project
        buildConfigField("String", "HASH_SALT", apiSaltHash)

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        packaging {
            resources {
                excludes += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
                excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE"
                excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE"
                excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
                excludes += "META-INF/ASL2.0"
                excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
            }
        }

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true

            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            enableUnitTestCoverage = true
            isDebuggable = true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        abortOnError = false
        ignoreWarnings = true
    }

    sourceSets.getByName("main") {
        resources.srcDirs(
            "src/main/res/layouts/main",
            "src/main/res/layouts/home",
            "src/main/res/layouts/rewards",
            "src/main/res/layouts/registration",
            "src/main/res/layouts/order",
            "src/main/res/layouts/more",
            "src/main/res/layouts/profile",
            "src/main/res/layouts",
            "src/main/res",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox/debug",
            "src/main/res/layouts/main/sandbox/release"
        )
    }

    flavorDimensions.add("minApi")

    productFlavors {
        create("flavour 1") {
            applicationId = "com.flavour.one"
            targetSdk = 30
            minSdk = 26
            versionCode = 10
            versionName = "1.0.0"
            dimension = "minApi"
   
            resValue("string", "app_name", "Sandbox")
            resValue("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }

        create("flavour 2") {
            applicationId = "com.flavour.two"
            targetSdk = 33
            minSdk = 26
            versionCode = 36
            versionName = "4.0.0"
            dimension = "minApi"
            resValue("string", "app_name", "Sandbox")
            resValue("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }

        create("flavour 3") {
            applicationId = "com.flavour.three"
            targetSdk = 34
            minSdk = 24
            dimension = "minApi"
            versionCode = 90
            versionName = "2024.5"
            resValue ("color", "splashbackgroundcolor", "#ff0d0d0d")
        }
}


Are those the only two references from BuildConfig that are unresolved? Or are the other values unresolved as well?

Hi @tomerpacific, only those 2 fields.. I have flavours.. so those fields aren't defined in defaultConfig, they are only defined per flavour.. I will update the original question with the configs mentioned
